# Kivy Image and Widget in different locations after rotation

Tags: kivy

i tried to rotate my widget with:

```
with self.canvas.before:
        PushMatrix()
        Rotate(origin=self.center, angle=90)

with self.canvas.after:
        PopMatrix()
```

But my widget and the image it contains are in different places, i display the widget position with:

```
with self.root.ids.background.canvas:
   Color(1, 0, 0, 1, mode='rgba')
   Rectangle(pos=self.root.ids.ship.pos, size=self.root.ids.ship.size)
```

also the widget collide method suggest the same finding i have with painting the position.
Doesnt matter if i use Scatter or Image class, both times when i rotate the Image ends up in a different place. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr5Ks.png)

i also tried to control the position with:

```
self.children[0].pos = self.center
```

here is the complete git repo:
[The link to the github repo to be able to test it yourself](https://github.com/Hazzel1337/kivy-space-game)

Comment: It's somewhat likely that `self.center` at the time your code runs isn't the same as `self.center` once the app has fully initialised, so the origin of the rotation is not what you intended.

Comment: i am setting the position in the init function manually, doesnt seem to change anything        self.pos = (100,100)
        self.children[0].pos = self.pos

Answer (score 0):

i am now using https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.rotabox for my rotation issue and it works great